# Firebase Query-based Security Rules not working on Simulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to test simple code on firebase realtime database -> Rules->simulator but it cant read. Just I am trying this simple code from [docs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/01/introducing-query-based-security-rules.html)

```
"JetonAlanlar" : {      
              ".write": "auth != null && !root.child('Banned').hasChild(auth.uid)",                 
              "Sorular":{
                "Tarih":{

                  ".read": "query.orderByKey && query.limitToFirst <=30"

                },
              }
          },
```

and this is simulator run code:

```
/JetonAlanlar/Sorular/Tarih
```

Simulator says read permission denied. is this problem on simulator or Firebase Realtime database does not support query based rules.

editted:

this is my code which is querying in android app

```
public class SorularFragmentYeni extends SoruAdaptor {


    public SorularFragmentYeni() {}

    @Override
    public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

    ... 

        return databaseReference.child("JetonAlanlar/Sorular").child("Tarih");
    }
}
```

also

```
public abstract class SoruAdaptor extends Fragment implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

...

public abstract Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference);

}
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't test query based rules in the simulator. You will have to test them in actual code.

Comment: unfortunately real device also give Permission denied

Comment: In that case I suggest you update your question with your datastructure and the code you are using to query the database and I will see if I can help you :)

Comment: I've editted my question

Comment: Is that all the relevant code? All I see there is getting the database reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As André commented: the rules simulator for the Firebase Database does not allow you to simulator a query. It merely simulates a read from a location, or a write to a location. This explains why your read doesn't work: your rules only allow a query, and the simulator does not use a query.

Your code also doesn't return a query:

```
databaseReference.child("JetonAlanlar/Sorular").child("Tarih")
```

This code is merely a read from a location, which your security rules don't allow. If you want to allow this read operation, your rules should be:

```
"JetonAlanlar" : {      
  "Sorular":{
    "Tarih":{
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to keep your current rules, you need to make sure your code matches what the query allows:

```
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

    ... 

    return databaseReference.child("JetonAlanlar/Sorular").child("Tarih")
                            .orderByKey().limitToFirst(30);
}
```

It's a common mistake to think that the security rules will add those last two clauses for you. That's not how Firebase's security rules work though: Firebase simply checks whether your query is allowed according to the rules.